# How to get the ARN of the load balancer in .ebextensions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to add a cloudwatch alarm to an elastic beanstalk environment using ebextensions.

So I created a `.ebextensions/cloudwatch-alarms.confg` file that looks like the following:

```
Resources:
  ELBLatencyAlarm:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
    Properties:
      AlarmDescription: { "Fn::Join" : ["", [{ "Ref" : "AWSEBEnvironmentName" }, ": HIGH ELB latency." ]]}
      Namespace: AWS/ApplicationELB
      MetricName: Latency
      Dimensions:
      - Name: LoadBalancer
        Value : "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:xx-xxxxxx-1:123456789012:loadbalancer/app/awseb-AWSEB-oooooooooooo/12b68287xxxxxxxx"
      Statistic: Average
      Period: 300
      EvaluationPeriods: 1
      Threshold: 
        Fn::GetOptionSetting:
          OptionName: ELBLatency
          DefaultValue: "0.5"
      ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanThreshold
```

One thing that I haven't figured out is how to use functions to get the ARN of the load balancer.

The arn of the load balancer, `arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:xx-xxxxxx-1:123456789012:loadbalancer/app/awseb-AWSEB-oooooooooooo/12b68287xxxxxxxx`, is created by elastic beanstalk. I don't know it before the environment got created.

I think probably I can use the functions described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions-functions.html) to get the arn of the load balancer. But I haven't figured how to do it.

Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-loadbalancer.html#aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-loadbalancer-return-values):

> When you pass the logical ID of this resource to the intrinsic Ref function, Ref returns the Amazon Resource Name (ARN) of the load balancer.

So if you're using a current-generation load balancer (ie ALB or NLB, not CLB), you should just be able to use the `Ref` function on the load balancer's logical name:

```
Value: !Ref MyLoadBalancer
```

I have also found [this list](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-format-resources-eb.html) of 'built-in' beanstalk resource-names very useful for getting properties associated with pieces of the architecture that are auto-generated for use in templates.

FYI the "logical name" of a resource is usually one you assign it, as a child of the `Resources` property in your template, e.g.

```
Resources:
   MyLoadBalancer:
   ...
   MyS3Bucket:
   ...
```

The logical names here are `MyLoadBalancer` and `MyS3Bucket`. If you have not defined them then use the names in the list linked above, so your load balancer will probably be either `AWSEBLoadBalancer` or `AWSEBV2LoadBalancer`, depending on whether it's a classic or current-gen load balancer.

Comment: What's the logical name in my case? Can you explain more about it?

Comment: I guess the logical name of the load balancer looks like `awseb-AWSEB-C1XXEWXXXXX`. However, this name is also created by elastic beanstalk.

Comment: the "logical name" is either the one you have chosen in your template at the `Resources` level, or the one used automatically by beanstalk in the list linked in my answer. I'll add an edit

Comment: I don't know it before the EB environment got created.

Comment: Thank you. [The list](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-format-resources-eb.html) helps me a lot. I use `Value : { "Ref" : "AWSEBV2LoadBalancer" }` to get the arn of the load balancer.