# How to describe an instance in AWS CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to write an cloudformation template where a security group ingress rule will contain an security group of an existing EC2 instance.
**It should have the following property:**

- User dont have to enter the security group as parameter.
- Cloudformation will not create the ec2.
- Instead the cloudformation will search for that existing instance and findout its security group and then we will use that using Fn::GetAttr may be.

I know we can do a describe-instance from aws cli and put the security group as input of cloudformation template but I was thinking can the same be done from Cloudformation template itself.

A small example would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I was thinking can the same be done from Cloudformation template itself.

Yes, it can be done using [custom resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html). The custom resource would a lambda function which would use AWS SDK's `describe-instance` to do the search, find the security group id, and return to the CloudFormation.

Regarding the **example**, you can have a look at my answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65677754/awswafv2webaclassociation-resourcearn-for-application-load-balancer-in-cloud/65729457#65729457). For the answer I developed similar custom resource. It was getting info about Elastic Beanstalk resource, but it could be modified to use `describe_instances` instead of `describe_environment_resources` to suit your needs.